# OpenSSL session pool in shared memory

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I would like to create a pool of TLS connections/session in shared memory so I can use the TLS connections in multiple processes. Each process will check available/free connection and start using it instead of creating new connection per process. I will add locking mechanism to make sure only 1 process can access use it.

I am able to create connection pool for local connections where I can pass file description over UDS within processes. Want to know if we can do same with TLS connections? Here I am trying to avoid TLS negotiation per process.

I am developing in C or C++ on Linux.

Comment: Have you verified that opening these connections is even measurable in your program?  My gut says the complexity of the code you'll need will dwarf any performance gains you might get (and I'd be surprised if this would be a performance gain).

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with openssl. The structs hold pointers to other allocated data iirc, which doesn't play well with shared memory.

Comment: While you can share memory, I'm not sure you can share other essential components like sockets and file descriptors using shared *memory*. Why are you considering a multi-process approach? These days the trend is *strongly* towards a single process with threads where necessary, but with a heavy emphasis on async operations.

Comment: TLDR:  That's what threads or reverse proxies are for.  If you insist on continuing, you'll have to reimplement OpenSSL to put the entirety of its TLS state tracking into shared memory.  Securely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Re-implementing the stack is not strictly necessary. Although I have not tested it, one can use `CRYPTO_set_mem_functions` to rebind the allocation functions OpenSSL would use to implementations provided by the programmer. These implementations could obtain memory from a shared memory pool. However, all the processes would need to map that shared memory to the same base pointer.

Comment: This cannot be done, for a number of fundamental reasons. This kind of a feature must be directly supported by the shared library, it cannot be hacked on top of it. OpenSSL has no such feature documented anywhere in its published API documentation.

Comment: @jxh Good point. That appears to be [a 1.1.1 addition](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/CRYPTO_set_mem_functions.html).  I'd think there could still be problems with syncing actual file descriptors for the TLS connections across processes though.  At best, it'd be a fragile, difficult-to-maintain beast with no performance advantages over reverse proxying the TLS connection and sharing straight TCP sockets, or just using multiple threads.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, it seems more straightforward to allow each process to maintain their own distinct connection pools.

Comment: @StephenNewell I tried pool of TLS connections in single process and observed performance improvement as it completely avoid TLS handshake part. Also my code has logic to clear sessions to avoid any security issues.I agree there are lots of efforts to support it.

Comment: @jxh Thanks for pointers. I will continue to look into these memory functions to allocate space on custom memory location.